# Что значит многоточие в обработчике исключений?

Tags: c++, исключения

```
try
{
    throw 21;
}
catch(...)
{
    std::cout << "..." << std::endl;
}
```

Что это за механизм и как он устроен (как работает)?

Comment: Ловит все исключения которые не вошли в другие `catch` блоки, ставиться всегда последним блоком, если их несколько.

Comment: Многоточие даёт возможность задать переменное число параметров. т. е. параметров может быть 1, может 2, 3... (в вашем случае - любые исключения)

Comment: @InDevX Вы путаете использование многоточия в разных контекстах.

Comment: @VTT вполне вероятно. не столь сведущь в плюсах, как хотелось бы

Comment: @VTT тем не менее в стандарте [связь просматривается](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.handle#5).

Answer (score 0):

Данный тип "ловит" любые исключения.

Обычно `...` используется в случаях, когда необходимо поймать любое исключение и затем выкинуть определённое кастомное исключение.

```
try
{
    throw 21;
}
catch(const MyException& E )
{
}
catch( ... )
{
    std::cout<<"..."<<std::endl;
    throw "Specified Exception";
}
```

Comment: Этот код некорректный, т.к. блок с ... должен быть последним.

Comment: он необязательно должен стоять в конце, то что этот эксепшн не словился указывается в комментарии

Comment: он обязан идти последним. На это есть соответствующее требование стандарта языка. `If present, a ... handler shall be the last handler for its try block.`

Comment: признаю ошибку.

Comment: Нет какого-то обязательного требования что-то выкидывать из обработчика с троеточием.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ стандартные компиляторы (gc++, vc++) всё равно не дают так просто скомпилить

Comment: @Komdosh достаточно добавить ключик `-fpermissive` и получить [предупреждение вместо ошибки](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8iZizw0WBo6LS6bG). Суть в том, что стандарт явно не запрещает использовать обработчик с троеточием выше других обработчиков, но вот разумность такого кода может быть поставлена под сомнение. Это как код после `return`, например, он недостижим, но компилятор разрешает такое.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ну да, вот можно, но всё равно вряд ли человек непонимающий что такое `...` добавит этот ключ

Comment: @Croessmah возможно, я всё же что-то путаю :)

Comment: Непонятно только, почему вы называете `...` "оператором".

Comment: Ну а что это такое?

Comment: У "это" в терминологии С++ нет специального названия, кроме как "ellipsis" ("многоточие"). Термин "оператор" же в С++ имеет четкое значение, которое с `...` ничего общего не имеет даже отдаленно.

Comment: @AnT ладно, исправил

Comment: @αλεχολυτ вы путаете то, что запрещает стандарт с тем, что разрешает ваш конкретный компилятор. Стандарт в [пункте 18.3/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/except.handle#5) ясно говорит "_If present, a ... handler shall be the last handler for its try block._". А ключ `-fpermissive` переключает GNU-совместимые компиляторы в режим допущения того, что не допускается стандартом C++. Не факт, что подобный режим есть, например, у MSVC++ или у каких-то других не совместимых с GCC компиляторов.

Comment: @Ruslan у msvc есть аналог: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39112170. Про необходимость уже выяснили, просто комментарии удалены.